# How to read the specific file (.xml) in the parent folder and subfolder

Tags: c#

I'm still new to c# language. I want to write the code so that it can read the specific file like `xml` file type in the parent folder and its sub-folder.

I have tried out few codes I searched on stack and it works. The issue here it only read that `xml` file in the parent folder only and not in the sub-folder.

Example:

I have a folder (D:\data) and inside 'data' folder it has another folder which is 'input' folder. Both of the folder will have xml file.

The code will only read the xml file in 'data' folder and not 'input' folder.

I want it to read all xml file in all folder available inside 'data' folder including the file in 'data'

Can someone give me some link or hint how to code this. Your guy's help is really appreciated here!

Example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String folderpath = @"d:\data";

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderpath, "*.xml"))
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
        Console.WriteLine(contents)
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET has methods to get subfolders within a directory, list file names, etc.. Do some research on what you need. A simple Google search on "c# get subdirectories" provided me with more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.EnumerateFiles`, as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx#Syntax), accepts a parameter (the third and last one) that does exactly what you need.

If no parameter is passed only the top-level directory will be searched, by passing `SearchOption.AllDirectories` as last parameter, the search will also include all sub-directories.

Example:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderpath, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
    Console.WriteLine(contents)
}
```

Comment: I'll add the code here later. I'm outside right now and using app to reply your comment.